# Reclassify very high resolution raster with R/GDAL

Tags: raster, gdal, r, reclassify

I am currently processing a new crop type map for Europe, which can be downloaded from here: https://data.jrc.ec.europa.eu/dataset/15f86c84-eae1-4723-8e00-c1b35c8f56b9 (~ 6GB). The map depicts the locations of 19 crops at a resolution of 10x10m. I want to convert it into 19 maps, where each pixel shows the share of a specific crop on a 250x250 grid. I am looking for a workable solution that does this for one crop. With this available I can create a function and loop it over all crops with lapply.

My current approach for maize (value 216 in the crop map) is to create a map where all observations for maize are recoded to 1 and the rest to 0 using the R Raster package. In the next step I am running gdalwarp (using the R gdalUtilities package) and calculate the average over a grid of 250x250m. This should give the correct result but unfortunately the reclassification does not work due to the size of the raster. This does not seem to work as even after running for more than 6 hours using a subset of the data (a province in Luxembourg), I get the following error message:

In writeBin(v, x@file@con, size = x@file@dsize) :
problem writing to connection

I can see that Raster created several very large files but there is still around 20GB left on my HD (216 GB free HD and 32 RAM). Perhaps the reclassification part can be done with GDAL (through R, which I prefer to use) as well? In my experience GDAL is often more powerful than the Raster package, particularly when large files need to be processed. This is the REPEX:

```
# Packages
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(gdalUtilities)
library(tictoc)
library(dplyr)

# Load map
input <- file.path("c:/temp/EUCROPMAP_2018.tif")
r <- raster(input)

# Get Luxembourg polygon
poly <- st_as_sf(getData(name = "GADM", country = "LUX", level = 2))

# Reproject
poly <- st_transform(poly, crs(r))

# select a province
poly <- poly %>%
  dplyr::filter(NAME_2 == "Vianden")

# Crop
r_crop <- crop(r, poly)
plot(r_crop)
plot(poly$geometry, add = T)

# reclassify raster to select maize (maize code = 216)
# 22655.12 sec processing and error messages!
tic()
s <- calc(r, fun=function(x){x[x != 216] <- 0; return(x)})
s <- calc(r, fun=function(x){x[x == 216] <- 1; return(x)})
toc()

# Calculate average for a raster of 250x250m
# This part is not implemented as the reclassification in the previous step failed.
output <- file.path("c:/temp/maize_share_250m.tif")
gdalUtilities::gdalwarp(input, output,  tr = c(250,250), r = "average")

plot(raster(output))
```

Comment: Any chance you can make your province raster subset available on Dropbox or some other sharing site to save us a 6Gb download?

Comment: I just put the r_crop file (tif) and a copy of the EUCROPMAP_2018.tif on my Dropbox, so please have a look: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9v1vo98wh21y6ak/AADkex-_BDYkORI8VP8Wz_H9a?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting but very large data set. I'm afraid you have to partition the data set in some way. If I try to access the raster in a "sequential" table form, I get the following message:

```
as.data.frame(rst.large)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 654.7 Gb
```

Based on your country approach I've written a small R-Sketch with a moderate runtime behavior. For Luxembourg the calculation needs about `3 minutes`, to aggregate (sum) a set of crops in 250x250 m cells.

You can run this over the complete EU and could use a different partition polygons for larger countries. Aftermath the several country results could be merged with the `gdal_merge.py` tool.

BTW do you have a documentation for the crop tags?

### Resultion dataset 250 x 250 m crop selection coverage

[image]

[image]

### Documented R Sketch

```
# CLEANUP -------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# Clean up a previous session
rm(list=ls())

# Load the raster and vector driver kit
require(rgdal)
require(raster)
require(sf)
require(tictoc)

# 1. Global settings --------------------------------------------------------
# Set the work and data directory my images are in 'WORK_DIR/data' 
DATA_DIR   <- sprintf('%s/%s', getwd(), 'data');

# Settings 250 x 250 m 
PATCH.SIZE   <- 250 
EUROPE       <- 'EUCROPMAP_2018'
COUNTRY      <- 'LUX'

# The selected crop types 
# sort(unique(tab.country$tp))
CROP.SELECT <- c(211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217)

# 2. Data access as proposed ------------------------------------------------
# Create the file names 
file.large   <- sprintf('%s/%s.tif', DATA_DIR, EUROPE)
file.country <- sprintf('%s/%s_%s.tif', 
                        DATA_DIR, EUROPE, COUNTRY)
file.country.250 <- sprintf('%s/%s_%s_250.tif', 
                        DATA_DIR, EUROPE, COUNTRY)

# Open the large raster file 
rst.large  <- raster(file.large)


# Open a layer to partition the large set here the country polygon
poly.country.orig <- st_as_sf(getData(name = "GADM", 
                                      country = COUNTRY, level = 2))

# Use the projection of the raster
poly.country <- st_transform(poly.country.orig, crs(rst.large))

# Create a subset for the country
rst.country <- crop(rst.large, poly.country)
tab.country <- as.data.frame(rst.country, xy=TRUE)

# Shorten the column names
names(tab.country)  <- c('x','y','tp')

# 3. Create the crop statistics in larger cells -----------------
# ix and iy are the new aggegation factors 250x250 m
tab.country$ix <- trunc(tab.country$x/PATCH.SIZE)*PATCH.SIZE
tab.country$iy <- trunc(tab.country$y/PATCH.SIZE)*PATCH.SIZE

# Prepare the counting for the crops
tab.country$crop <- 0
# If the tag is in the list set a one as proposed
tab.country$crop[ tab.country$tp %in% CROP.SELECT ] <- 1

# Aggregate the crop type using sums in the larger cell conglomerate 
# My device needs for the aggregation in larger cells about
# 171.379 seconds for Luxembourg
tic('aggregation in larger cells')
tab.250 <- aggregate( crop ~ ix + iy, data = tab.country, FUN = sum)
toc()

# Calculate the norm ..25x25 = 625 to ge the right percentage
# TODO NA values are not considered yet 
res.country <- res(rst.country)
norm.cells  <- prod( c(PATCH.SIZE, PATCH.SIZE)/ res.country)

# Create the average .. IMO it is a percentage of crop cells
tab.250$crop <- tab.250$crop/norm.cells

# 4. Translate the table based data back to a raster -------------- 
rst.250 <- raster(
              ncol = length(unique(tab.250$ix)),
              nrow = length(unique(tab.250$iy)),
              xmn  = min(tab.250$ix),
              xmx  = max(tab.250$ix),
              ymn  = min(tab.250$iy), 
              ymx  = max(tab.250$iy),
              crs  = crs(rst.large))

cells <- cellFromXY(rst.250, tab.250[,c('ix','iy')])
rst.250[cells] <- tab.250$crop       

# Show a summary
summary(rst.250)
hist(tab.250$crop*100,
     main='Aggrgation of crops in 250x250m cells',
     xlab='Crop coverage in %' )

# Plot the raster 
plot(rst.250)
plot(poly.country$geometry, add = T)

# 5. Store the resulting raster ------------------------------------
writeRaster(rst.250, file.country.250)

# EOF.SKETCH
```